# Are there advantages to a crashing on a secondary thread versus the main one?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, winapi, crash

I came across this code in a large codebase

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc (LPVOID lpParam)
{ 
    int *x = 0;
    *x = 1234; // Access violation

    return 0; 
}

void Manager::Crash ()
{
    Log("Received a remote command to crash Server.");

    DWORD dwThreadId, dwThrdParam = 1; 
    HANDLE hThread = ::CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunc, &dwThrdParam, 0, &dwThreadId);
}
```

My question is: Why is it using a thread? Would it be more or less threadsafe if the code in `ThreadFunc` was done directly in `Manager::Crash`? I am reluctant to make changes in case I remove the crash.

Comment: Where did you get this code from?

Comment: Interesting thought experiment, but this isn't a great title. How about "Are there advantages to a crashing on a secondary thread versus the main one?"

Comment: @quixoto: good title, fixed. @Maz: why?

Comment: Huh... Why not just call exit() or terminate() ?  This is incredibly complex code to shutdown your server...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He doesn't want to handle the exception that occurs. The original thread that received the `Manager::Crash` continues. An AV exception does not necessarily terminate the process. Although in this case the fact that is not handled by a `__try/__except` block (note, is a [SEH try block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s58ftw19%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), not the C++ one)  then the unhandled [second chance](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105675) exception *will* terminate the process. But perhaps he want to force [Dr. Watson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Watson_%28debugger%29)/[WER](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/winlogo/maintain/StartWER.mspx) to jump in, or the [post-mortem debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff542967%28VS.85%29.aspx) to launch, or to break into current debugger. Who knows...

Actually, d'oh! IF the main thread *does have* a SEH handler installed, it will not crash the process. QED.

Comment: I'd word that as "He doesn't want any thrown exceptions handled. The original thread might have a SEH block, and would catch it."

Comment: @GMan: Yeap, I'm pretty sure that's it, avoiding any SEH installed in the main thread(s). Saw your comment up right after I edited my 'd'oh' moment :)

Comment: This is totally something that deserves a comment in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to ask whichever programmer wrote it in the first place, but probably the rationale behind crashing in a thread like that was to get around an exception handler designed to catch segfaults in the main thread. This might be a good time to break out your source control's time-lapse view and email the perpetrator.

That's also an unnecessarily clumsy way to induce a CPU exception, by the way. You can trigger a crash or breakpoint directly by using *eg* [__debugbreak()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f408b4et.aspx) or an inline assembly `int 3`. That will cause the program to break into the debugger immediately, which by default in most MSVC programs will dump core if no debugger is attached.

Comment: +1 for noting that this is a fairly JV way to induce a crash if you want to be sure that one happens.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason for this to be in a separate thread unless you have more work to do after the thread that we are not seeing. I'm guessing that the main thread catches it for some reason. I'd rather catch it when it happens then have it percolate to the top personally.

Why crash the server? Sounds like a poor design choice to me.

Comment: How about if you need to test your post-mortem dumper and error reporting infrastructure? A way to crash the process on-demand it sure is handy.

Comment: @0A0D: Seems like this could well be part of some unit testing infrastructure. :)

Comment: @quixoto: More like integration testing to me

Comment: @0A0D: its fine even in a production server as long as the authority to **use** the crash server command is suitably restricted. Don't want to give out a DOS attack for free, naturally.

Comment: If it was for unit testing, you would want it to get into the SEH.

Comment: Or maybe it's a section of "unreachable code", and crashing the server is safer than continuing in an unknown/unexpected mode of operation.